# Im creating a dict but I really want a list, what is the syntax in this case?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

In a for loop I have the following:

```
aContract = {'name': 'abc', 'type': 'xyz'}
if 'contracts' in alist:
    alist["contracts"].append(aContract)
else:
    alist["contracts"] = aContract
```

So json is being returned to me and inside the json we have bool's, dict's, list's etc.  'contracts' is in this json as a list. I can append things to it just fine when my code is in the if statement.  However, when 'contracts' does not exist (we are in the else statement), I'm trying to create it (unsuccessfully) and add aContract to it.  So the else statement makes it a dict and the next time through when I try to run

```
alist["contracts"].append(aContract)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I created a dict when I wanted a list.  So how do I make 'contracts' exist as a list and then add 'aContract' to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the dictionary in a literal list:

```
aContract = {'name': 'abc', 'type': 'xyz'}
if 'contracts' in alist:
    alist["contracts"].append(aContract)
else:
    alist["contracts"] = [aContract]
```

Better still, use [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) here to skip having to test for the key:

```
aContract = {'name': 'abc', 'type': 'xyz'}
alist.setdefault("contracts", []).append(aContract)
```

`dict.setdefault()` will set the key to the default value given if not yet present, then returns the value. So, if `alist` has no key `'contracts'`, it'll set the value to an empty list.